# Basic Tensorflow Model shows random outcomes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am working on building some new models, and wanted to get back to some basics. So I decided to write a classifier that classifies [1, 1] as a 1 and all other combos as a 0.

I have written several different variations on this and keep getting mixed results.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow import keras

data = [[1., 1.], [1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0., 0.]]
results = [[1.], [0.], [0.], [0.]]


def build_model():
  model = models.Sequential()

  model.add(layers.Dense(len(data[0]), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1))

  model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=[keras.metrics.Accuracy()], optimizer='adam')

  return model


model = build_model()

model.fit(data, results, epochs=1000)
model.summary()

print(model.predict([data[0]]))
print(model.predict([data[1]]))
print(model.predict([data[2]]))
print(model.predict([data[3]]))
```

Sometimes the output is completely wrong:

```
[[0.]]
[[0.]]
[[0.]]
[[0.]]
```

and the model never gets accurate.

```
Epoch 1000/1000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 910us/step - loss: 3.8562 - accuracy: 0.7500
```

Sometimes it shows lower accuracy and produces bad results:

```
Epoch 1000/1000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 918us/step - loss: 3.8562 - accuracy: 0.2500
```

```
[[-0.1101699]]
[[-0.13835455]]
[[-0.03829439]]
[[0.]]
```

Other times it "kinda" works:

```
Epoch 1000/1000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 898us/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

(although I would expect accuracy to be 1)

```
[[1.1292353]]
[[-0.167045]]
[[-0.03134967]]
[[-0.3522459]]
```

Could someone help me understand the variance in my outcomes. I have created several version of this model with more layers, less layers, various sized Dense() layers. I have tried several loss and metrics, however, at this point I am just randomly doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a binary classification problem (i.e. binary cross-entropy loss and accuracy metric), you should **not** use a `linear` activation function for your last layer, which is the default one, if you don't specify anything, like here; from the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/):

> **activation**: Activation function to use. If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: `a(x) = x`).

A linear activation in the last layer for a (binary) classification problem is meaningless; so, change your last model layer to:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

and you should be fine (see also [Train accuracy decreases with train loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387251/train-accuracy-decreases-with-train-loss) and [Model not learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177605/model-not-learning)) .